# Debug Reaction-Commerce web shop based on Meteor

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I installed [Reaction-Commerce](https://reactioncommerce.com/) on a Ubuntu (Trusty).
Now I would like to debug/customize the project. For this purpose I installed [Atom](https://atom.io/)  since it was mentioned on the project site.

How can I hook a debugger to the running "reaction" project?

What Atom package do I need?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Atom, but VSCode is similar. Here's how I was able to setup debugging:

1. Create new reaction project from Terminal
2. `mkdir test`
3. `cd test`
4. `reaction init`
5. `cd reaction`
6. Open vs code from Terminal (must be in the reaction dir) `code .`
7. Click on debugging (there should be ‘No Configurations’ in the drop-down)
8. Click the gear icon to create a new Node.js configuration
9. Edit `launch.json`: 
   configurations.program -> `“${workspaceoot}/server/main.js”`
10. Save the file
11. Navigate to `/server/main.js`
12. add `debugger;` before `Startup();`
13. Save the file
14. Open Integrated Terminal (View | Integrated Terminal)
15. Type: `reaction debug`  [it will start the app and eventually pause at the debugger statement]
16. Once it says that it’s paused, switch to the debug view in the left nav and select "Attach to Process" from the dropdown.
17. Then press the ‘start’ button (and select the Node.js process)
18. You should see the execution paused on the debugger statement entered in Step 12.
19. At this point you can step in, out, or over code statements.